# delete file after serving over HTTP in play framework - java

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

How do i delete a file after serving it over http,

```
        Files.TemporaryFile file = null;
        try {
          file = new Files.TemporaryFile(f);

            return ok().sendFile(file.file());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return badRequest(Json.newObject().put("message", e.getMessage()));
        } finally {
           file.clean();
        }
```

with this code, the file gets deleted before it is served. i receive an empty file on the client.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cleanup after sending a file in Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38851210/cleanup-after-sending-a-file-in-play-framework)

Comment: @Mike - the link is really nice, but it's about Scala version. Java version doesn't support the `sendFile` method with `onClose` handler (as far as I can see it will be fixed in Play 2.8).

Answer (score 1):

Play framework in version 2.8 should support `onClose` argument in `sendFile` method also in Java (so far it seems to be supported only in Scala version).

In older versions (I have tried only on 2.7.x) you may apply the same approach like in the fix for 2.8, so:

```
public Result doSomething() {
    final File fileToReturn = ....;
    final Source<ByteString, CompletionStage<IOResult>> source = FileIO.fromFile(fileToReturn);

    return Results.ok().streamed(wrap(source, () -> fileToReturn.delete()), Optional.of(fileToReturn.length()), Optional.of("content type, e.g. application/zip"));
}

private Source<ByteString, CompletionStage<IOResult>> wrap(final Source<ByteString, CompletionStage<IOResult>> source, final Runnable handler) {
    return source.mapMaterializedValue(
            action -> action.whenCompleteAsync((ioResult, exception) -> handler.run())
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading the [`JavaFileUpload` documentation for 2.6.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaFileUpload), it sounds like you don't need that `finally` block to clean up the file afterwards. Since you are using a `TemporaryFile`, garbage collection should take care of deleting the resource:

> ...the idea behind `TemporaryFile` is that it’s only in scope at completion and should be moved out of the temporary file system as soon as possible. Any temporary files that are not moved are deleted [by the garbage collector].

The same section goes on to describe that there is the potential that the file will not get garbage collection causing Denial Of Service issues. If you find that the files are not getting removed, then you can use the `TemporaryFilesReaper`:

> However, under certain conditions, garbage collection does not occur in a timely fashion. As such, there’s also a `play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFileReaper` that can be enabled to delete temporary files on a scheduled basis using the Akka scheduler, distinct from the garbage collection method.

Comment: i copied the file to a fileinputstream and deleted the actual file. This way, i dont have to use a scheduler.

Comment: but, i dont think thats the ideal way. play for scala has an onclose method where u can clean the temporalfile. im looking for something which works along those lines. what i have now is a hack.

Comment: Sorry, I may just be missing something. Have you tried my answer yet? I think it might be as simple as running your function without the `finally` block, and then verifying that the file has been removed after waiting for sometime for garbage collection to occur.

Comment: I've also assumed that you have the ability to use 2.6.x. If that's not the case, then my answer doesn't work.

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is, delete the file as soon as the request is complete. Not wait until the garbage collector runs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not forcing all the project, but you can use a Scala for only this controller, then you can use `onClose` parameter of the `sendFile` method. The only attention - that parameter is not workable in all versions, it looks like in 2.5 there was an issue so it was not triggered (was not work: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6351).

Another way - you can use Akka streams, like here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaStream#Chunked-responses.